# io.emit works, but socket.emit doesn't (Node.js, Express, React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I have recreated a basic "ping-pong" code example in Node.JS, Express and React with Socket.io

Tho, the code works with `io.emit('pong')` but not with `socket.emit('pong')` and I can't figure out why.

## Code:

### Client

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, React } from 'react';


// Main
const Test = () => {
    const socket = io();
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(socket.connected);

    // UseEffect
    /// Initialize the socket
    useEffect(() => {
        // Connection
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            setIsConnected(true);
        });

        // Disconnection
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            setIsConnected(false);
        });

        // Pong
        socket.on('pong', () => {
            console.log("pong");
        });

        // Turning off socket
        return () => {
            socket.off('connect');
            socket.off('disconnect');
            socket.off('pong');
        };
    }, []);


    //// Send a ping
    const sendPing = () => {
        socket.emit('pingSocket'); // Doesn't work
        socket.emit('pingIo'); // Works
    }


    return <button onClick={() => sendPing()}>
                Send ping
            </button>
}

export default Test;
```

### Server

```js
import express from "express"; // Express
import cors from "cors"; // CORS
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);


// Socket 
/////////
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} connect`);

    socket.on('pingSocket', () => {
        socket.emit('pong'); // Doesn't work
    });

    socket.on('pingIo', () => {
        io.emit('pong'); // Works
    });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 5000.");
});

export default io;
```

When there is only `socket.emit("pingIo")`: "pong" **is** logged
When there is only `socket.emit("pingSocket")`: "pong" **isn't** logged

##### Note

`pingSocket` and `pingIo` are both accessed. Checked with a `console.log` on the server.

Comment: I think it is because your connection is done with `io` object. Socket is returned to be used in the callback, but when you try to reply on the same connection, you need to use `io` because that did the connection.

Comment: your code is confusing. `//// Send a ping
    const sendPing = () => {
        socket.emit('pingSocket'); // Doesn't work
        socket.emit('pingIo'); // Works
    }
` is it `io.emit('pingIo')` works

Comment: @Yilmaz no. If you want to emit data to the server, you should use `socket.emit`. The difference between both `socket.emit` is that, they don't emit the same thing. And the problem isn't on the first data sent by the client, because the server receive both.